# memcached client to prefer localhost before using other addresses?

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached, failovercluster

We're running memcache on the same node as our app server. If the web app needs an item from memcached, we want to access the local memcache instance for obvious reasons, but if it's not up, default to a cluster address where several remote memcache instances are bound.

This appears to work in spymemcached, it uses localhost first, unless localhost is not available.

```
MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient(
  AddrUtil.getAddresses(
    "localhost:11211 memcachecluster:11211"));
```

The only issue we have is, if `localhost` is not available, the client resorts to `memcachecluster`, and that's fine for failover, but we've got lots of memcache instances listening on that address, so it becomes very unlikely for `localhost` to be used again even if it comes back online unless the app server is recycled, which we normally do during deployments anyway but not that frequently.

Is there a way for spymemcached to always **prefer** `localhost`, provided its available, even if the client has other addresses?